# c# selenium automation. if my website is down send a mail to my id

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing a automation in c sharp selenium in chrome web browser. If my website is down or slow ,a mail have to send to my Email ID.can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a Selenium issue. Try going to Pingdom Tools. 
https://www.pingdom.com/ or Site24x7.com.